# Character by character output to simulate a typing effect

Tags: c++

How would one would approach a situation where you want to output character per character in a C++ Program, to simulate a typing action?

Comment: Exactly which part of it are you struggling with? I can think of lots of ways to achieve this, but it really depends on which part you are having problems with to explain what you need.

Comment: I want to write a function that I can give a string, and it outputs it character by character

Comment: @Rijnhardt And what have you tried already to solve that problem?

Comment: Do you mean that it should output the characters at intervals of time, or between some user input?

Comment: Like I stated in my question, how do I approach this? What is the best way to do it. If you can please give me a general idea. Ill then try my best to figure it out.

Comment: So, `for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) cout << str[i];`

Comment: The characters should appear one at a time on the console. Asif it was typed into it.

Comment: @MatsPetersson (with `sleep(1);` interspersed)

Comment: You probably want to put something like `usleep` in Mat's loop.  At least I think that is the effect you are going for.

Comment: C++11: [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: You'll also have to flush after each character.  Otherwise, it won't (necessarily) be output.  (IIRC, the standard requires unit buffering for `std::cout` _if_ the device is considered interactive.  But I seem to remember, too, that not all implementations are conform, and that some use line buffering, which isn't officially part of C++.)

Comment: To make it look more natural you might also add a random element to the sleep time.

Comment: @confusopoly: You'd need a timer capable of high precision sleeps, or else a rather large variation in inter-character timing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: 300 characters per minute would be 200ms per character, with say a variance of 100ms. That doesn't sound all that high-precision to me.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: (C++11)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello!";

    for (const auto c : s) {
        std::cout << c << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (although I suspect it should).  Adding a flush after each `std::cout << c`, or setting `unitbuf` makes it work.  (And of course, unless you've got C++11, you'll need some other timer.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Hmm, added a modifier that flushes the stream, although I don't see that it is necessary. It might be good practise to output a newline after the line is complete though :)

Comment: @JamesKanze C99, 7.19.3/7; it only states that the standard streams are *fully buffered* **iff** they refer to interactive devices.

Comment: @snipes83: Your change helps not at all.  It only forces the entire line to appear after all sleeps have completed -- which doesn't mean output at regular intervals.

Comment: @snipes83 I _think_ that `std::cout` is supposed to be unit buffered, at least if it refers to an interactive device.  In which case, the flush or the modifier shouldn't be necessary.  In practice, it is, at least on my system: all of the output ends up buffered until the end of the program (or an explicit flush).  Try using `std::cout.setf( std::ios_base::unitbuf );` before entering the loop.

Comment: @JamesKanze only `cerr` is unit-buffered, [narrow.stream.objects]/5

Comment: @DyP And leaves the definition of an interactive device up to the implementation:-).  With g++ under Linux, outputting to an xterm apparently isn't considered interactive.  (In addition to using `unitbuf`, you could probably use `setbuf` with a 0 length buffer, to get unbuffered.)

Comment: @DyP The buffering policy is thus based on C, with unit buffering replacing unbuffered and line buffered.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `usleep(ms)` function from lib C, between each character you want to write. It works.

Comment: Assuming it's not on a Windows system... ;)